# Difference of Two Types of Return in bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Say I have following node.js code

```js
function foo() {
    return promiseOne().then(function(result) {
        return promiseTwo();
    });
}
```

What's the difference between these two "return"s? I know the purpose of 2nd "return" is to make promiseTwo() thenable. Do I have to have the 1st "return"? I guess it comes down to the scope of 2nd "return"? Because if I call `foo()` somewhere and I don't have 1st 'return', then I will not get anything back?

Comment: your promises won't chain properly if you omit the returns.

Comment: @Alnitak There is a point to the second return? It seems like it wouldn't return anything. Are you saying the way he has it in the question will wait for the second promise to return before returning from `foo()`?

Comment: @VSO no, AIUI kind of the opposite will happen - the `.then` call won't realise that `promiseTwo()` is returning a promise and will return immediately instead of returning the new promise that waits for `promiseTwo` to be fulfilled  [although none of the above will happen until `promiseOne()` has been fulfilled first]

Comment: @VSO Inside `then()` function, you have to `return` a promise in order to chain promises together. Otherwise, it will just default return `undefined` and go to next `then()`

Comment: So, my understanding is that Amber's answer is the closest to correct. Your function would need to return a promise that returns only after the nested promise is resolved. You can also use $Q to chain promises. I can post an example later if no one does.

Comment: @VSO it's "correct", but IMHO confusingly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference between these two "return"s?

The first one returns a promise that is returned by the `.then()` method call that is invoked on the result of `promiseOne()` function call. The second one returns the promise that is returned by `promiseTwo()` function call.

> Do I have to have the 1st "return"?

No if you don't want the promise to be returned from the `foo()` function and yes if you do.

> Because if I call foo() somewhere and I don't have 1st 'return', then I will not get anything back?

That's true for any function. If the function doesn't return anything then you will not get anything back. It's true no matter what the function returns - a promise or anything else.

If the `foo()` function doesn't return a value then you will not be able to do any of:

```
let promise = foo();
foo().then(...);
foo().catch(...);
let value = await foo();
try { await foo(); } catch (err) { ... }
```

The last one would only catch exceptions thrown by the `foo()` function itself, it wouldn't catch the promise rejection if you don't return the promise from the `foo()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The first (outer) `return` is there to make the result of `foo()` itself into a "thenable".

Note also that the function *could* have been written like this:

```
function foo() {
    return promiseOne().then(promiseTwo);
}
```

since `.then` will do the right thing when passed the function reference - the anonymous wrapper in the original code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain Promises or simply access its fulfilled value via `.then()`, you always have to return a Promise.

You want to use your example like this:

```
foo().then((value) => console.log(`My value is ${value}`));
```

If you remove your first `return`, it will throw an `undefined is not a function` error, because the return value of `foo()` does not have a `then()` function.

If you remove your second `return`, your script will run, but your `value` is `undefined`.

Only if you have both `return`s, `value` is the returned value of `promiseTwo()`.

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence - this seems a perfectly fine use of Promises.

Comment: Okay, that might have been too opinionated. Therefore I removed the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the `return`s, both return from the respective function. Notice that you have two functions in your code, and both must return a promise to work as expected (to allow their caller to wait for the result):

```
function() {
    return promiseOne().then(…);
}
function(result) {
    return promiseTwo();
}
```

The only difference would be in the returned values - the result of `then` vs `promiseTwo` -, and where the functions are called - the outer is usually called explicitly by user code as `foo()`, while the inner one is called as a `then` callback.